# Change existing .NET Entity Framework layer from Sql Server to MySql

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

**Question** : I have an web application that uses .NET Entity Framework library to access a Sql Server Database. What should I do to change it to MySQL ?

**Some more details**

I tried changing the parameters in app.config and here is my app.config file.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="mysql_db" connectionString="server=localhost;user id=root;password=;database=foo" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
     <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6, Version=6.9.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"></provider>
     </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

I ran the app after using the above file and I get the following error.

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

What else should I change to make it use a MySQL database. I have installed the necessary tools (MySQL, .NET MySQL Connector,  MySQL for Visual Studio).

Answer (score 1):

I think you should install  MySQL Connector/Net  and the configure a proper connection string (this is a sample) 
[Here you can find doc x ef6](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework60.html)

```
        <connectionStrings>
            <add name="MyContext" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" 
                connectionString="server=localhost;port=3306;database=mycontext;uid=root;password=********"/>
        </connectionStrings>
        <entityFramework>
            <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework"/>
            <providers>
                <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" 
                    type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6"/>
                <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
                    type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer"/>
            </providers>
        </entityFramework>
```